# Google Maps Android api circle bound

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-android-api-2

I got a question in my mind about how can I bound 2(or more) circle via android api.

[image]

The right side of the image is what I exactly want.

this is how can I creating my circle.

```
circle=mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
.center(geoPoint
.radius(40)
.fillColor(0x12541252)
.strokeWidth(3)
.strokeColor(Color.RED));
```

I really will be glad, if you suggest me any way to solve my this problem..! thanks in advance!

Comment: You can set Shape overlays order by setting their Z-indexes. By Default all the overlays has ZIndex=0. First circle's ZIndex should be lesser than second and then you can achieve you desired result as in above image. Please follow the link to get more help about https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Circle.html#setZIndex(float)

Answer (score 0):

The order in which this tile overlay is drawn with respect to other overlays (including GroundOverlays, TileOverlays, Polylines, and Polygons but not Markers). An overlay with a larger z-index is drawn over overlays with smaller z-indices. The order of overlays with the same z-index is arbitrary. The default zIndex is 0.

Overlays (such as circles) with higher zIndices are drawn above those with lower indices.

You should use the method mentioned below with [Circle](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Circle) and the ZIndex values for both the [Circle](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Circle) should be different

```
public void setZIndex (float zIndex)
```

To get more help follow this link:
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Circle.html#setZIndex(float)